# detect multiple values in column. Then loop through those values

Tags: c#, linq

Thanks for your ideas in advanced. I'm not sure if there's a way, but it's worth a shot.

Below you'll see the code I'll be referring to. The code I created works great; however, when looping through to copy to `dtPeople`, there are multiple values (comma delimited and in quotes) in `t.Field<string>("Source")`. I need to loop through those values, create a new row with the same info on the row, just will have a different `t.Field<string>("Source")`.

```
DataTable dtPeople = 
    (from t in tempDtUsers.AsEnumerable()
      where t.Field<string>("role").ToLower() == "user"
      select dtPeople.LoadDataRow(new object[]
      {
        Id,
        t.Field<string>("SourcedIds").Substring(6),
        t.Field<string>("Source"),
        t.Field<string>("FName"),
        "",
        t.Field<string>("LName"),
        t.Field<string>("Email")
    }, false)).CopyToDataTable();
```

Example of how it's writing to the DT:

```
"999999","060","100110257","Billy",,"Bob","bb@test.org"
"999999","168","101912217,100110265","Joe",,"Shmo","js@test.org"
```

Need it to come out like:

```
"999999","060","100110257","Billy",,"Bob","bb@test.org"
"999999","168","100110265","Joe",,"Shmo","js@test.org"
"999999","168","101912217","Joe",,"Shmo","js@test.org"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` to project `Source` into multiple items:

```
var dtPeople = new DataTable();
tempDtUsers.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(t => t.Field<string>("role").ToLower() == "user")
    .Select(t => new
    {
        Id,
        SourcedIds = t.Field<string>("SourcedIds").Substring(6),
        Source = t.Field<string>("Source"),
        FName = t.Field<string>("FName"),
        MName = "",
        LName = t.Field<string>("LName"),
        Email = t.Field<string>("Email")
    })
    .SelectMany(x => x.Source.Split(',').Select(source => dtPeople.LoadDataRow(new[]
    {
        x.Id,
        x.SourcedIds,
        source,
        x.FName,
        x.MName,
        x.LName,
        x.Email
    }, false)))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Edit: CopyToDataTable takes `IEnumerable<T> where T: DataRow` only. I thought `T` can be any class...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm just learning about linq. I've haven't wrote it this way before. I'm getting a "anonymous type" error, not sure why. Id is a var string that's already available before the tempDtUsers is filled. So when it's looping through, its not getting it from the tempDtUsers. Hope that makes sense

Comment: I should say I'm new to lambda expressions

Comment: It is hard to guess what the error is based on what you've provided. Can you copy the exact error message and paste it here and also indicate which line the error is from? And, sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @54696d fixed the issue with "anonymous type"

Comment: That did it. You are awesome! I going to set some time aside and learn lambda now. Thanks!